# Prometheus client make_asgi_app returns empty dictionary on multiprocess mode

Tags: python, prometheus

I've made a custom exporter to expose some data from gitlab to prometheus using the prometheus_client and I've parallelized the process using multiprocessing pool.

So far I was successful when using start_http_server module but I wanted to switch to FastAPI + Gunicorn like it's described [here](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#fastapi--gunicorn).

**Server app:**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from prometheus_client import make_asgi_app
from gitlab_exporter_func import *
from gitlab_exporter_var import *
import time, os, shutil
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI(debug=False)

@app.get("/metrics")
def get_metrics_app():
    start_time = time.time()

    if os.path.exists(prome_stats):
        shutil.rmtree(prome_stats)
    os.mkdir(prome_stats)

    projects_ids=get_projects()
    get_pipejobs_data(projects_ids)

    end_time = time.time()
    execution_time = end_time - start_time
    print("Execution time:",execution_time)

    return make_asgi_app(registry=registry)

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return "Go to /metrics for gitlab metrics"      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

I'm initializing the registry on a different *gitlab_exporter_var* like so:

```
registry = CollectorRegistry()
multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(registry)
```

*PROMETHEUS_MULTIPROC_DIR* is setup through the environment and points to a folder in the same directory as the scripts.

When I start the server, requests are handled as expected and data's getting collected and I can see *PROMETHEUS_MULTIPROC_DIR* getting populated but /metrics returns "{}".

For reference **http server** that works:

```
import prometheus_client
from prometheus_client import start_http_server
from gitlab_exporter_func import *
from gitlab_exporter_var import *
import time
import os
import shutil

prometheus_client.REGISTRY.unregister(prometheus_client.GC_COLLECTOR)
prometheus_client.REGISTRY.unregister(prometheus_client.PLATFORM_COLLECTOR)
prometheus_client.REGISTRY.unregister(prometheus_client.PROCESS_COLLECTOR)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start up the server to expose the metrics.
    start_http_server(8000, registry=registry)
    while(True):

        start_time = time.time()

        if os.path.exists(prome_stats):
            shutil.rmtree(prome_stats)
        os.mkdir(prome_stats)

        projects_ids=get_projects()
        get_pipejobs_data(projects_ids)

        end_time = time.time()
        execution_time = end_time - start_time
        print("Execution time:",execution_time)
        
        time.sleep(max(0, 60-execution_time))
```